Can a householder without a mantra initiation, perform homa regularly at home?
Can a householder do homa of a deity without initiation into a mantra of that particular deity? Also if initiated into the mantra, Is purascharana of mantra compulsory before homa?

As per scriptures, mantra needs initiation. To do purascharana a person needs permission of guru. Homa is part of purascharana.
